# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 able to maximize the internal vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

I am doing a program on mesh simplification and I faced a problem. As the faces and vertex I read in is of huge amount, when I try to do some processing on those faces like (finding the normal of each faces, tracking out the edges) my loops can go up to a few thousands or even ten thousands.

However when I try to debug, the program will crash and give me a message that the

```
vector subscript is out of range
```

Error occur at here in the internal `<vector>` file:

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (size() <= _Pos)
        {   // report error
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
        _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
        }

 #elif _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 1
    _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(_Pos < size())
```

So I wonder if there is any way that I can maximize the vector for MVS 2010? Sorry if my question sound stupid.

ok: below is my code:
I am finding the normal of each face

```
Face *f;
Point P1;
Point P2;
Point P3;
Point normal;

for(int i=0; i<F.size(); i++)
{
    f = F[i];
    P1 = V[F[i]->a]->coord;
    P2 = V[F[i]->b]->coord;
    P3 = V[F[i]->c]->coord;

    float V21a = P2.x - P1.x;
    float V21b = P2.y - P1.y;
    float V21c = P2.z - P1.z;
    float V31a = P3.x - P1.x;
    float V31b = P3.y - P1.y;
    float V31c = P3.z - P1.z;

    normal.x = V21b*V31c - V21c*V31b;
    normal.y = V21c*V31a - V21a*V31c;
    normal.z = V21a*V31b - V21b*V31a;

    float normalize = sqrt(pow(normal.x,2) + pow(normal.y,2) + pow(normal.z,2));

    normal.x = normal.x / normalize;
    normal.y = normal.y / normalize;
    normal.z = normal.z / normalize;

    float d = -1 * (normal.x*P2.x + normal.y*P2.y + normal.z*P2.z);

    f->plane[0] = normal.x;
    f->plane[1] = normal.y;
    f->plane[2] = normal.z;
    f->plane[3] = d;

}

F is a list of faces
V is a list of vertex
```

The program works absolutely fine if F.size() is less than 500 but crashes when goes above that.

Comment: That's where the error is being reported, but not where the error is. You are trying to access an element that is not in the vector.

Comment: You need to show **your** code. You're accessing the element which is out of the vector's range.

Comment: Probably cause you have a *bug* such as using reserve and expecting it to work the same as resize.

Comment: ok. I shown my code as above :)

Comment: And which line exactly is triggering the assertion? Probably: is `V` large enough so that all of `F[i]->a`, `F[i]->b` and `F[i]->c` are `< V.size()`?

Comment: yes. Basically the a,b,c of F is the vertex index in the vertex list

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the problem is not the size of F.

I'd look at:

```
P1 = V[F[i]->a]->coord;
P2 = V[F[i]->b]->coord;
P3 = V[F[i]->c]->coord;
```

At this point, you are probably trying to access an index within V that does not exist.
A look at the callstack at the time when the error occurs should reveal where the invalid value came from.

You could also add some asserts at these lines to let the debugger give you an error as soon as a value goes out of bounds.